# Laravel and SQL good practices for types

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with `"types"` that looks like this :

```
Common, Rare, Mythic, New
```

and an `"item"` table that has a type as a foreign key. In fact Common are common to all of types except New. Instead of doing a 0..n relation I wanted to put what's common on all columns except "New"

Is it possible through Laravel Eloquent or is it just a bad practice to try like this?

Thanks you!

Comment: Sure, you could use a `string` or `enum` column.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you give me a little example please? I'm not sure how I should do it!

Comment: It's just a column on the table. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following points should be considered about ENUM usage:

**ENUMs work best when**

- The type you are representing is local to the table only
- It must represent a type that is never changed
- It will never likely experience redefinition
- Its cardinality needs to be low
- Its portability must always be based on logical dumps of the table, never physical.

**When not to use ENUM**

- When ENUM type is not fixed
- When ENUM type has a long list of values
- When your application does not know the list of ENUM values
- ENUM type is not reusable
- Portability is a concern

I hope these points will help you.